# How to create a delete button in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I made another Column in my `GridView` called delete. When delete is clicked, the row should be deleted or in other words, I need to get the current row's user name to delete it.

1. Which event should I use? (RowDeleting, Rowdeleted etc...)
2. How do I get the username from the current row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a great article about [typical usages of DataGrid](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/212_How_to_edit_and_Delete_records_in_a_gridview_using_datakeys.aspx).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `RowDeleting` event, by storing the user name in the data key collection you can access it programmatically.

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="UserName" ID="GridView1" 
     runat="server" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
```

Then, in the code behind use the data key to delete the record.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
  string userName = (string) GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
  DeleteUser(userName); 
}
```

Comment: I like examples like these, but I can only seem to find examples where the `DataGrid` control will only use hard coded column names. My data is filled behind the scenes based on user inputs, calling one of 10 different stored procedures, to display different summaries - therefore, different column names.

Answer (score 1):

1:-

```
protected void grdLst_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)

{

    int i = Convert.ToInt32(grdLst.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    ob.DeleteCoverage(i);
    Response.Redirect("fullcoverage.aspx");
}
```

2:-

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdlist.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
    Response.Write(name.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tablename.Rows.RemoveAt(datagrid1.currentcell.rowindex);
```

Comment: I want to delete the user from the database thus deleting him from the Gridview. I need to get the username

Comment: @OrBetzalel: Given the `columnIndexOfUsername` and using the **GridViewDeleteEvent** (see Phaedrus' post), you should be able to extract the `username` with something like: `username = datagrid1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnIndexOfUsername].Value.ToString();`