# GridView Page Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I'm using a GridView to show data from a database and I am having a problem with PageIndex, the pagination is working correctly, I can see all the information, but I have a problem with a button placed at the end of each row which action is delete a row

In the Grid View the button works absolutely fine in the first page the action of deleting the row works fine, but when I change to the second page

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll ("Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.")

The problem is that the Page Size for my GridView is set to 10, so in the first page the rows are set (obviously like an array) from 0 to 9, but when I change to the second page the array continues from 10 to 19, so if I click the button on the first row of the second page the CommandArgument returns "10"

[image: debug result of command argument]

(which translates to the 11 element on an array) and it's bigger than the page size of the gridview

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        FillGrid();
    }

public void FillGrid()
    {
        Methods metodos = new Methods();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM ul";
        GridView1.DataSource = metodos.Query(query);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The error happens here

```
if (e.CommandName == "btnDelete")
        {   
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            //Get row number
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        }
```

The variable index returns 10 and the error occurs because that value (11 element in the array) is bigger than the page size of the grid and it's not "finding" the row like the error says `less than the size of the collection`

I have tried setting the GridView1.PageIndex = 0; but the pagination stops working, if place the databind after setting the GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; the pagination stops working again

EDIT: This is the button on the gridview

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Delete CommandName="btnDelete" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CausesValidation="false"/>
```

Comment: How are you doing your delete? Normally one would pass the record ID back in the command and use that (not the index) for deleting.

Comment: Did you use custom paging template? Consider setting `CommandArgument` attribute like this: `CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>'`. Better to show your delete button markup there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry I edited the question with the code of the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a delete button in GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447180/how-to-create-a-delete-button-in-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem coming from the `CommandArgument` property definition below:

```
CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>"
```

According to the reference, `DataItemIndex` returns a value regardless of current page number, and `Rows` collection indexes depend on [`PageSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize?view=netframework-4.7.2) setting which never exceeds page size limit, therefore `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will thrown while accessing `Rows` collection with respective index.

A simple workaround for this issue is using modulo operation from `PageSize` property of the grid against `CommandArgument` and use its value as row index:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "btnDelete")
    {   
        int index = (Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)) % GridView1.PageSize;

        //Get row number
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
    }
}
```

Reference:

[GridViewRow.DataItemIndex (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitemindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Similar issue:

[“Index was out of range” when Accessing the DataKeys Collection in a Paged GridView](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2013/11/14/error-index-was-out-of-range-when-accessing-the-datakeys-collection-in-a-paged-gridview.aspx)